# How to post video properties with youtube-data-api on c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try to upload videos to my youtube account with youtube api v3 on asp.net. I searched a lot but didn't find any code sample to do this. Actually now i can upload videos somehow but i can't give name, description etc. to my videos. Here's my code which i use to upload my videos.

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {access_token}");
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/videos/test.mp4"));
        byte[] response = wc.UploadData(uri, file);

        string jSonResult = String.Format("\nResult received was {0}",
              Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response));
        return jSonResult;
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Googles Client library?

Comment: No. but i just can't let it work. In my scenario, user will not login because already i upload videos to my channel. When i try to use that library im stuck about credentials. If you have any sample code i can try.

Comment: you have to be logged in to upload a video.

Comment: I use a tokken which i generated from dev console. So i take video from my user and upload it to my channel. Why user should login ? it's not about user account

Comment: Dev console doesn't give you a token for uploading, you need to be authenticated first.    There is a sample for uploading on the documentation page.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert   There is documentation on authentication here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: The code above just upload videos without asking login because i already generated oAuth key which auto refresh itself and i just past it to code. And the link u sent, when i want to use this code of course it ask me for login to my account and give permission to my app. Btw I really thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you already found a solution.
But this code works on my machine! ;)

```
    byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    //byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(videoFilePath);

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(videoFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + authToken);
        request.ContentLength = jsonBytes.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString());
        request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Type", "video/*");

        string location = string.Empty;
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                location = response.Headers["Location"];
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

        request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(location);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + authToken);
        request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
        request.ContentType = "video/*";
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            var data = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, data);
            //dataStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I actually fixed my problem but your code works, so this is the answer for my question. Thank you